# Correct pattern to configure objects built by Factory

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory

I've had this problem tickling me for the past weeks; my current implementation works, but I'm curious to know if there is a "good way" to do this. I'm new to design patterns, so this might be a stupid question.

Put simply, you have:

- An object prototype providing an interface (let's call it abstract kernel);
- Specific kernels implementing the above interface in various ways;
- A concrete kernel Factory;
- Another object Foo, which stores a pointer to an abstract kernel, as is returned by the Factory.

My problem is this; specific kernels implementations may define their own set of parameters, which differ from one kernel to another. 
Foo uses kernels to do some processing, but this processing ultimately depends on these parameters, and I don't know how to configure those in a nice way.

I don't want to go for an abstract factory, and configure the concrete factory before building, because this seems wrong to me; it's not the factory that has parameters, it's the kernel.

But on the other hand, even if I set the kernel pointer in Foo as public, I can't access the parameters of the underlying kernel since they're not part of the prototype's interface... I'm sure other people had this problem before, maybe there's a simple solution I don't see. :S

Thanks in advance!

NOTE: In my current implementation, there is no kernel Factory. I put the kernel concrete type as a template of Foo, and set the kernel as a public member, which allows me to configure the kernel after the declaration, and before to start the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a piece of code knows what concrete kind of kernel it works with, it should have a pointer to that specific concrete kernel type. If it doesn't, it cannot access its specific  parameters (but can possibly access all parameters in a generic way as suggested by  @Jaywalker).

Your current implementation seems to go the first route, which is perfectly OK.

I have very limited info about your design, but it looks like you have several concrete kernel types, a separate builder for each type, and a separate configurator for each type. Packing all the builders into a Factory is problematic, as there's no clean and elegant way to forward concrete kernel types to their respective configurators (without things like `*_cast<>` or double dispatch). There are at least two ways to solve this and still have a Factory:

1. Bundle each builder with its respective configurator, and pack all the bundles into a Factory that churns out configured kernels.
2. Bundle each kernel with its configurator and make a Factory producing these bundles (this way a kernel may be configured any number of times during its life cycle).

Comment: In this case, and following your comments and Jaywalker's, I think going for a generic solution would obfuscate the code more than making it cleaner, as I only have a few concrete kernel implementations so far, and it's not expected to get much bigger. One comment though, regarding your post and Jaywalk's; Foo needs not know about the parameters of the kernel, only about the prototype's interface -- but the kernel does require to be configured beforehand.

Comment: Can't the kernel "read" the configuration from somewhere else if `Foo` doesn't need to know about these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Anything which is not part of the prototype interface will not be available in `Foo`, as you have said. It simply doesn't make sense to use the factory pattern if `Foo` knows the specifics of each kernel implementation.

In some limited circumstances, adding something like following getters and setters in the prototype interface could get your work done:

```
virtual bool setParameter (const string &key, const string &value) = 0;
virtual string getParameter (const string &key) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I was afraid of. The main problem with virtual key-value setters/getters is that it's a pain to implement, in order to account for any type of parameter.